# Handling Success and Error API responses in Logic Apps workflow part 2

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics

I am bulding a Logic Apps workflow and I need to handle 2 different type of responses returned back by a 3rd API service by using an if condition.

The API response in case of the API being able to process the data correctly looks pretty much like this:

`[ { "Input": { "Address": "", "Address1": "Sageweg 27", "Address2": "Neuenburg", "Address3": "", "Address4": "", "Address5": "", "Address6": "", "Address7": "", "Address8": "", "Country": "DEU", "SuperAdministrativeArea": "", "AdministrativeArea": "", "SubAdministrativeArea": "", "Locality": "", "DependentLocality": "", "DoubleDependentLocality": "", "Thoroughfare": "", "DependentThoroughfare": "", "Building": "", "Premise": "", "SubBuilding": "", "PostalCode": "79395", "Organization": "", "PostBox": "" }, "Matches": [ { "AQI": "A", "AVC": "V44-I44-P6-100", "Address": "Sägeweg 27,79395 Neuenburg Am Rhein", "Address1": "Sägeweg 27", "Address2": "79395 Neuenburg Am Rhein", "AdministrativeArea": "Baden-Württemberg", "CountryName": "Germany", "DeliveryAddress": "Sägeweg 27", "DeliveryAddress1": "Sägeweg 27", "GeoAccuracy": "P4", "GeoDistance": "0.0", "HyphenClass": "C", "ISO3166-2": "DE", "Country": "DE", "ISO3166-3": "DEU", "ISO3166-N": "276", "Latitude": "47.807820", "Locality": "Neuenburg Am Rhein", "Longitude": "7.569160", "MatchRuleLabel": "Rlfnp", "PostalCode": "79395", "PostalCodePrimary": "79395", "Premise": "27", "PremiseNumber": "27", "SubAdministrativeArea": "Reg.-Bez. Freiburg", "Thoroughfare": "Sägeweg" } ] }, { "Input": { "Address": "", "Address1": "Schubartstr. 111", "Address2": "Bietigheim-Bissingen", "Address3": "74321", "Address4": "", "Address5": "", "Address6": "", "Address7": "", "Address8": "", "Country": "DEU", "SuperAdministrativeArea": "", "AdministrativeArea": "", "SubAdministrativeArea": "", "Locality": "", "DependentLocality": "", "DoubleDependentLocality": "", "Thoroughfare": "", "DependentThoroughfare": "", "Building": "", "Premise": "", "SubBuilding": "", "PostalCode": "", "Organization": "", "PostBox": "" }, "Matches": [ { "AQI": "A", "AVC": "V44-I44-P6-100", "Address": "Schubartstr. 111,74321 Bietigheim-Bissingen", "Address1": "Schubartstr. 111", "Address2": "74321 Bietigheim-Bissingen", "AdministrativeArea": "Baden-Württemberg", "CountryName": "Germany", "DeliveryAddress": "Schubartstr. 111", "DeliveryAddress1": "Schubartstr. 111", "DependentLocality": "Bissingen", "GeoAccuracy": "P4", "GeoDistance": "0.0", "HyphenClass": "C", "ISO3166-2": "DE", "Country": "DE", "ISO3166-3": "DEU", "ISO3166-N": "276", "Latitude": "48.942220", "Locality": "Bietigheim-Bissingen", "Longitude": "9.106600", "MatchRuleLabel": "Rlfnp", "PostalCode": "74321", "PostalCodePrimary": "74321", "Premise": "111", "PremiseNumber": "111", "SubAdministrativeArea": "Reg.-Bez. Stuttgart", "Thoroughfare": "Schubartstr." } ] } ]`

while in case of "error" looks like this:

`{ "Number": 18, "Description": "Missing or invalid parameters", "Cause": "A required parameter was not supplied of the value of a parameter cannnot be converted into the right type.", "Resolution": "Check the parameters passed and their values against the specification for this service." }`

How can I set the schema for the Parse JSON action considering that in the success case it's an array, while in the error case it's an object?

Apologies if I previously asked again this question but the success response I pasted here was wrong, by bad.

Thanks all for the time spent in helping.

Comment: "What to do if nobody answers your question" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265233/what-should-you-do-if-nobody-answers-your-question-can-you-repost-it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve though?  I suspect you want to split the direction of the flow depending on the response, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below given schema to parse both the success and failure response.

```json
{
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Number": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "Description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Cause": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Resolution": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Input": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "Address": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address3": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address4": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address5": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address6": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address7": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Address8": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Country": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "SuperAdministrativeArea": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "AdministrativeArea": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Locality": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "DependentLocality": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "DoubleDependentLocality": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Thoroughfare": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "DependentThoroughfare": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Building": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Premise": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "SubBuilding": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "PostalCode": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Organization": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "PostBox": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Matches": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "AQI": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "AVC": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Address": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Address1": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Address2": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "AdministrativeArea": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "CountryName": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "DeliveryAddress": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "DeliveryAddress1": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "DependentLocality": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "GeoAccuracy": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "GeoDistance": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "HyphenClass": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ISO3166-2": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Country": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ISO3166-3": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ISO3166-N": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Latitude": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Locality": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Longitude": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "MatchRuleLabel": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "PostalCode": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "PostalCodePrimary": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Premise": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "PremiseNumber": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Thoroughfare": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- Given schema works for both array type success response and object type failure data.

**Success Payload**-

[image]

**Failure Payload** -

[image]